# Rails friendly_id doesn't render on existing user on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, friendly-url

I am using the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem to make my url friendly & replace id by username in the url for example. Everything works fine under development, because I was about to run (to update currents users url):

`User.find_each(&:save)` in my rails c.

But in production mode, on heroku, It works only with new users - How can I add the friendly_id models to existing users ?

I tried to run

```
Heroku run rake Pin.find_each(&:save)
```

But without success:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your application directory:

```
heroku run console
```

And then:

```
Pin.find_each(&:save)
```

Comment: ! thanks for your answer but now It returns => nil - strange  right?

Comment: Every Ruby method/object returns "something". What error do you get?

Comment: I know this is the error ! instead of updating the existing users - it returns => nil !